# Webcam + LED microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, usb-device, usb-hub

I want to make a simple USB device consisting of a webcam and some LEDs. The webcam will detect a human face using some software I've glued together (thanks, predator algorithm), and it will send a signal to the microcontroller to smoothly transition the LEDs from red to blue. I know how to do it with Arduino Uno and a webcam, but I want to find some good, cheap parts to substitute in.

For instance, what kind of micrcontroller do I need (a good, cheap one)? Do I need a USB hub to split between the microcontroller and webcam or is some other method preferable? What kind of webcam do I need? It should be small and cheap - high resolution or great picture quality isn't important.

Please help a software engineer who's an electronics n00b!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the red to blue LED transition?

Comment: If you're comfy using the Arduino Uno, the ATmega family of microcontrollers would be a good place to start - they're the micro used on the Arduino.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Eventually I want to encorporate facial recognition into my software and add biometric screening. But that comes later.

Answer (score 2):

So the webcam image is processed by a computer, which then tells the microcontroller what to do with the LEDs?

It seems like there are two completely separate parts to this project - a webcam and a microcontroller controlled LED display.

For the webcam: buy one that you like. We're not going to do your shopping for you. It has absolutely no bearing on the microcontroller, it's a webcam plugged in to your PC.

For the microcontroller - you have two broad choices - one with USB built in, and implement a USB stack in the MCU, or one with UART and use a USB to UART bridge, like an FT232 chip.

Which one to choose?  Your guess is as good as mine.  Pretty much any of them can interface to the computer either through USB or a USB to UART bridge.  Any of them can drive LEDs.  The task is a very simple one, so you don't need lots of memory or flash, so nothing fancy is needed.

And yes, a USB hub will connect both the webcam and the microcontroller to your computer.